# URL validation is not accepted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am validating an url with jQuery validate plugin. The jquery validate plugin has a url rule built in. [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method)

JavaScript is:

```
    $( "#form").validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            url: true
        }
    }
   });
```

My requirement is

1. jQuery validation plugin is necessary as it is validating properly,so it can't be changed
2. In addition to that it has to pass www.xxx.com. Because I will add http:// or https:// before validation. I need regular expression to pass www.xxx.com . The regular expression that can be added should not affect other jQuery validation plugin behaviors.

Comment: What *does* it do? What input are you providing it that's not validating correctly?

Comment: It doesn't allow `www.xxx.com` because it's not an URL - it's a string.

Comment: `www.xxx.com` is just a domain name, not a URL. If you want to validate it as URL, you’ll have to make it one first.

Comment: View this URL it has some useful info [Click Here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method/)

Comment: @h2ooooooo You got +9k and make a comment like that?

Comment: @h2ooooooo- I know that it is a string. I am just asking is there any way to pass this too(www.xxx.com).with jQuery validation plugin

Comment: @coolprarun - The same link I attached in my question. My requirement is different

Comment: What is your requirements? keep it more clear please and once check my attached link in my answer, if you can use regular expressions.

Comment: updated some more in my question. this explains clearly my requirement

Comment: You mean www.xxx.com? :) i is missing before xxx?

Comment: Strings start with `"` and end on `"`, I don't see any of them beside the line which you're saying isn't a URL :)

Answer (score 0):

Your link is working perfect you just need to add/send url like :

> http://www.google.com

and if you want to validate url separatly then you can use:

> function makeUrl(url){
>
> ```
> var str = url;
> str = str.split("//");
> ```
>
> > ```
> > if(str[1] == undefined){
> >    str = "http://"+str;
> >    is_valid_url(str);
> > }
> > else{
> >    str = str;
> >    is_valid_url(str);
> > }
> > ```
>
> ```
> }
> ```

```
function is_valid_url(url)
    {
         return url.match(/^(ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\/?([^\s<>\#%"\,\{\}\\|\\\^\[\]`]+)?$/);
    }
```

[IT is the best link for your url validate method check it](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=1&categoryId=2)

Comment: but why he want to use plugin untill it can be done easily with some of js, jquery , regex direct method

Comment: Because form validation is much more than matching URLs.

Comment: @Anup and because sometimes you can't choose what to use due to his company's policy or whatever.. He asked for jQuery validator and that is what kind of answer he should get. It's not incorrect.

Comment: okay i updated my answer and also attach one important link for his

Comment: updated some more in my question. this explains clearly my requirement

Comment: yes it doesn't for that you need to add http:// dynamically or statically, i am updating  my answer wait for sometime

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to write your own validation method in this case:

http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod

```
function my_valid_url(url)
{
    // regular expression stolen from Anup's answer, hopefully it's correct. :)
    return ( url.match(/^(ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\/?([^\s<>\#%"\,\{\}\\|\\\^\[\]`]+)?$/)
          || url.match(/^[a-z0-9-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\/?([^\s<>\#%"\,\{\}\\|\\\^\[\]`]+)?$/) );
}

$.validator.addMethod('my_url', my_valid_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <meta charset=utf-8 />
   <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <textarea type="text" id="url"></textarea>
   <br/>
   <input type="button" value="test" id="btn" />
   <div id="result" />
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript :

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
var url = $("#url").val();
console.log(url);
if(checkURL(url)){
  $("#result").text("All ok");
}
else{
  $("#result").text("Not ok !");
}
});

function checkURL(value) {
var urlregex = new RegExp("^(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$");
if (urlregex.test(value)) {
    return (true);
}
return (false);
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sHvtr/)**

Comment: @coolprarun- jsfiddle example does not accept www.xxx.com. then what is the use of that??

Comment: It says not ok for www.xxx.com

Comment: updated some more in my question. this explains clearly my requirement

Answer (score -1):

This validation works correctly - you are just using a string. Try validating `http://www.xxx.com`

You're not getting the URL correctly if you have just `www.xxx.com`. Anyway just add the protocol back to the string and you should be fine.

Comment: he is asking for validate http(s):// also

Comment: @Anup http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure You're not trying to help and you downvote other people even if their answers aren't incorrect. You should be ashamed of how you behave.

Comment: I am trying to help but you aren't Mr. Dropout you down voted me not I am, other answer's also use my regex method because it is right method okay...